# How does one query an exact text-field and filter terms on another number-field in an ElasticSearch Index?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

I'm trying to query an index for all docs with matching values on specific text field, `Field_Name_1`, and filter those results to only show docs whose `Field_Name_2` field has any number value in the provided list, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

The problem I'm facing is the query will return docs that somewhat match the value in `Field_Name_1`, but I need to only return docs that match the value of `Field_Name_1` exactly. From researching, I believe I should have made `Field_Name_1` a keyword field, rather than a text field, because I will never need to run this query by providing the exact whole value of `Field_Name_1`.

Am I right in thinking I need to create a new index with `Field_Name_1` set to a keyword, then reindex? I haven't reindexed before, so I'm worried of losing data if I don't do it properly. Is there a way to perform this query with `Field_Name_1` being a text field?

These are the two queries I've tried, but they both return the same results. The only difference is the first query returns a "max_score" of 9.54, while the second query returns "max_score" of 0.

```
GET Index_Name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "Field_Name_1": "12345-1234-1234-1234-d123f123g123"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "Field_Name_2": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "track_total_hits": true
}


GET Index_Name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
             "Field_Name_1": "12345-1234-1234-1234-d123f123g123"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "Field_Name_2": [
              1,
              2,
              3,
              4,
              5
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "track_total_hits": true
}
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your index and your ES version? curl -X "GET" "localhost:9200/yourindex/_mappings"

Comment: @JuanCarlosAlafita Sure. Field_Name_1 is like this,

    "store_id" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }

The entire mapping of the index is too large to put here.

Answer (score 1):

**The `Field_Name_1` field should be of `keyword` type.**

This is because Elasticsearch uses a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) if no analyzer is specified. You can check the tokens generated using the analyze API as shown below -

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": "12345-1234-1234-1234-d123f123g123"
}
```

The tokens generated will be

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "12345",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "1234",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "1234",
      "start_offset": 11,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "1234",
      "start_offset": 16,
      "end_offset": 20,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "d123f123g123",
      "start_offset": 21,
      "end_offset": 33,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

---

To return docs that match the value of `Field_Name_1` exactly either you can change the data type of the `Field_Name_1` field to `keyword` type.

Modified index mapping will be

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Field_Name_1": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

OR if you have not explicitly defined any mapping, then you can also modify your search query like this :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "Field_Name_1.keyword": "12345-1234-1234-1234-d123f123g123"   // note this
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "Field_Name_2": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "track_total_hits": true
}
```

This will use the `keyword` analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after `Field_Name_1` field)

Comment: Field_Name_1 was explicitely defined as a text field, but I do have another field, which I defined as a text keyword, that I could use instead of Field_Name_1. Otherwise I would need to reindex the data into a new index which has the correct typing for Field_Name_1.

Is it possible to reindex into a new index of the same name, without losing any data? The name of the index matters in my case. Is there a way to get the current field types I've setup on the index, so I can just modify the ones that I need to when making the new version?

Comment: If I defined my mapping like this, how would I write to the keyword and search for the keyword?

```
 PUT my_index_name/_mapping
 {
 "properties": {
    "store_id": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

```

Answer (score 0):

I think what ESCoder wrote is the answer to your question.

Additionaly,

> "Scores calculated for queries in query context are represented as
> single precision floating point numbers"

In a filter context  no scores are calculated.  **Filter context** is mostly used for filtering structured data, e.g.
Is the Field_Name_1 field set to "12345-1234-1234-1234-d123f123g123"?

> "Frequently used filters will be **cached automatically** by
> Elasticsearch, to speed up performance."

If you require to match the value of Field_Name_1 exactly, you could use filters as a better option.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/query-filter-context.html

```
GET Index_Name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
             "Field_Name_1.keyword": "12345-1234-1234-1234-d123f123g123"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "Field_Name_2": [
              1,
              2,
              3,
              4,
              5
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "track_total_hits": true
}
```